# Zend_Auth login using either username or email as identityColumn

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

I'm using Zend_Auth with a "Database Table Authentication". What I want to do is allow the user to login with either a username or email address as the "identityColumn". How would I allow both. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Extend and implement your own Auth Adapter and use query like "WHERE username = ? or email = ?" to get Auth result :)

Comment: I would definitely implement my own auth adapter here. It's easier than you might think and you can copy/extend the DbTable adapter as appropriate

Comment: Thanks. I have one in place and just never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate twice (if needed) with 2 different `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` objects and add some logic to determine if the login is username or email by guessing if what type of login user provided so that you save one query for most of the cases.

Comment: This would do, but it's not a good design. You might want to use auth class elsewhere and you would copy this. DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the cleanest Zend_Auth implementation, but it works. The only problem comes if someone registers with an different email address as a username, but of course you can prevent this in your registration form. Hope it helps.

```
// if the entered value validates as an email address then use the 'email' field
// if not, use the 'username' field
$validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
if ($validator->isValid($form->getValue('password'))) {
    $identityField = 'email';
} else {
    $identityField = 'username';
}

$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
    $dbAdapter,
'users',
    $identityField,
    'password',
    'SHA1(?)'
);

$authAdapter->setIdentity($form->getValue('username'))
    ->setCredential($form->getValue('password'));
```