# Email address as login username - PHP & Zend_Auth?

Tags: php, authentication, zend-auth

I read an article showing how to do it to login using username.
Instead, I just want people to sign up and login using their email address since it is easier for them to remember.

Hope you guys can help. I'm creating a blog for high school science fair project.

Thanks!

Comment: An email address is a string just as an account is.  You'll just need different validation (Zend_Validate_Email or something like that...).  What specific problem(s) are you having?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend_Auth login using either username or email as identityColumn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386153/zend-auth-login-using-either-username-or-email-as-identitycolumn)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10419224/630316

this one the best one and i implemented this code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` You would just need to change the identity column to match email, rather than username.

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);
$authAdapter
   ->setTableName('users')
   ->setIdentityColumn('email')
   ->setCredentialColumn('password');
```

Have a look at the [Zend_Auth DbTable Docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html)