# Log in with username or email address

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a login with username or email

My code is:

```
$username=$_REQUEST['login'];
$email=$_REQUEST['login'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];

if($username && $password) {
  $query="select * from  user_db where username='$username'";
} else if ($email && $password) {
  $query="select * from  user_db where email='$email'";
}
```

Login with username is success but login with email is not working.

Comment: $email=$_REQUEST['login']; is this really email?

Comment: yes i have email in the user_db table

Comment: Check if $_REQUEST['login'] is set -- isset($_REQUEST['login']) and only set $username to that if it is set.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The login parameter is the same for both email and username. Not exactly incorrect if you have a single login box that accepts either.

You could put the condition in the query itself if you're not sure if it's an email or username.

```
$login=$_REQUEST['login'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE username='$login' OR email = '$login'"
```

A PDO-like solution is much more preferred nowadays as the above is subject to SQL injection. The logic stays the same, but you'd have it look something like this:

```php
$query = "
    SELECT * FROM user_db
       WHERE username = :username OR email = :username
";

$statement = $pdoObject->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(":username", $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the same value to two variables, and then using an if/else. Both if statements are equivalent.

You need to figure out if `$_REQUEST[login]` contains a valid email address, and if so use the email field of the database. Otherwise, use the username field.

Also, you should not be putting variables directly into the query. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

For me works something like this:

```
<?php  session_start();  include_once 'dbconnect.php';  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {   // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.     header('location:/error.php'); }

   
if ( !isset($_POST['emailuser'], $_POST['userPass']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}
$emailuser = ($_POST['emailuser']);
$emailuser = trim($emailuser);

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT userEmail or userName, userPass FROM users WHERE userEmail = ? or userName = ?')) {
   // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
   $stmt->bind_param('ss', $emailuser, $emailuser);
   $stmt->execute();
   // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
   $stmt->store_result();

   if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
       $stmt->bind_result($userName, $userPass);
       $stmt->fetch();
       // Account exists, now we verify the password.
       // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
       if (password_verify($_POST['userPass'], $userPass)) {
           // Verification success! User has loggedin!
           // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
           session_regenerate_id();
           $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
           $_SESSION['name'] = $emailuser;
           $_SESSION['emailuser'] = $userName;
           header('location: /menu.php');
       } else {
           echo 'Incorrect password!';
       }
   } else {
       echo 'Incorrect username!';
   }
   $stmt->close();    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username=$_REQUEST['login'];
$email=$_REQUEST['login'];
```

This is wrong, you are using `$_REQUEST['login']` for both email and username.  Why don't you just use email?

If `$_REQUEST['login']` doesn't have email address, of course this wont return you anything.

Also, both of your if statements will always execute, unless the fields are empty. right?

Take the login out, enforce the users to login with email addresses. also, take md5 of the password. who stores raw passwords these days?

Comment: @ Darth Vader i would like to provide an option for user only with one parameter either to  login with username or email